# jQuery Snippet Not Working on WordPress Site

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, wordpress-theming

> WordPress Version - 6.3.1
>
> Theme - JointsWP (blank starter theme)
>
> jQuery Version -  6.3.3 (tried 6.3.1 also)
>
> Website Link - https://legiondesigns.com/dev/labella/

***EDIT***: There are NO console errors either

I seem to be having a problem on my WordPress site. When running a jquery script in codepen.io everything functions properly. I AM using this code snippet on another site that I have designed years ago and it works fine using jQuery 6.3.1 but When running that code through my website it is not function properly at all.

Code snippet in question:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){
 $('.mobileBtn').click(function(){
  if( $('.mobileNav').hasClass('animate__zoomIn') ){
    $('.mobileNav').removeClass('animate__zoomIn').addClass('animate__zoomOut');
    $('.mobileBtn').removeClass('btnActive');
    setTimeout(function () {
      $('.mobileNav').css({display: 'none'}).removeClass('animate__zoomOut')
    },1000 );
    // alert('1');
  }
  else{
    $('.mobileNav').css({display: 'block'}).addClass('animate__zoomIn');
    $('.mobileBtn').addClass('btnActive');
    // alert('2');
  }
});
});
```

When I load this up on codepen.io (https://codepen.io/agon024/pen/KKBxNwx) it functions like it should.

I have disabled all the plugins and it still does it. I have removed all other jQuery from the script and it still does it. I have tried using "jQuery" instead of "$" and nothing. I am using this starter theme on another site and it doesn't have a problem.

**IMPORTANT** -
If I uncomment the "alert" lines I see that it is looping through the "if" and "else" statements  without stopping. When I click "mobileBtn" it adds the class "animate__zoomIn" and pops up an alert saying "2" then when I click OK on the alert it instantly removes the class "animate__zoomIn" and adds the class "animate__zoomOut", sets the inline style to "display: none" after 1000ms and pops up an alert saying "1" and when I click OK it stops.

Anyone know what is going on? Like I said it seems to be looping throught the "if" and "else" statements even when the "else" condition is met. This is the first time I have encountered this and seeing as it works on codepen it must have something to do with WordPress.

Comment: Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: @Unmitigated No, there are no console errors

Comment: Your codepen example doesnt work properly. Just click fast on your button and its over. Its not wordpress or jquery - its your snipped that doesnt work right. Heres a fiddle that might help you: https://jsfiddle.net/twc3m980/1/

Comment: @hes No its not the snippet. If you look at the code it has a timeout function that runs after one second. If you clicking it repeatedly then your not waiting the ons second timeout to occur and remove the class. I implimented your version of the script and it does the same thing just loops through the "if" and "else" statements. It adds "active" then immediatley removes it.

Answer (score 0):

This should work as desired.

```js
$('.mobileNav').addClass('animate__zoomOut').hide();
$('.mobileBtn').click(function(){
    $('.mobileNav').show();
  if ($(this).hasClass('btnNotActive')) {
            $(this).toggleClass('btnActive btnNotActive');
            $('.mobileNav').toggleClass('animate__zoomIn animate__zoomOut');
        }
    else {
        $('.mobileNav').toggleClass('animate__zoomIn animate__zoomOut');
        $(this).toggleClass('btnActive btnNotActive');
    }
  $(this).css('pointer-events', 'none');
   setTimeout(function(){
      $('.mobileBtn').css('pointer-events', 'auto');
  }, 1000);
});
```

```css
.mobileNav {
  background-color: red;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
}

.mobileBtn {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 50px;
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  width: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/4.1.1/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="mobileBtn btnNotActive show-for-small-only">
  Click Me
</div>

<div class="mobileNav animate__animated">
  <div class="mobileNavInner">
    <?php joints_off_canvas_nav(); ?>
  </div>
</div>
```